# Remove only <b> and <i> tags with PHP

Tags: php, html, tags, strip, strip-tags

strip_tags remove all tags except the allowable tags. How about the opposite? How can I only remove  and  but retain all other tags? I don't want to remove the contents inside the tags! Thanks!

Comment: that link is different. I'm not removing the content. And are you sure  str_replace can do that? How many cases would that have? I can add classes, ids, and all the things in the tags.

Comment: But what should happen with the content of the tags? Where should it go? It can't stay homeless.

Answer (score 1):

If the tags have no attributes, you can simply use

```
$html = str_replace(array('<b>', '</b>', '<i>', '</i>'), '', $html);
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest DOM Functions (please do not use regex).

Comment: Yes, lets teach the OP that this kind of "I've done nothing" question is acceptable.

Comment: and what if it contains attributes?

Comment: Why not regex? I think it would get the job done

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Answer (score 0):

I cant see whats wrong with Regular Expressions for these kind of tasks.

This would be my solution to:

```
$str = 'test <b class="abc">bold</B> <a href="test.html">testsite</A> <i>italic</i> more stuff <strong>strong</Strong>';
$html_clean = preg_replace('/<\/{0,1}[b|i][^>]*>/i','',$str);
echo $html_clean;
```

It does replace b and i tags only, including optional attributes inside the tags.

To include more Tags you would add them in the [b|i] Part.